# MySQL search value in two columns and sum third column

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table "game_info" I have

```
ID | player_1 | player_2 | score
--------------------------------
1  | John     | Rick     | 100
2  | Joe      | John     |  80 
3  | Bob      | Rick     | 210
```

I want to sum total score for every player no matter they are player_1 or player_2 and order by score.
What I expect is:

```
Name | Score
------------
Rick | 310
Bob  | 210
John | 180
Joe  |  80
```

I have tried to JOIN and UNION, but I can't get it right.

Is there any way to do this in sql or i have to redesign my table?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `union all` and `group by`:

```
select player, sum(score)
from ((select player1 as player, score from game_info
      ) union all
      (select player2 as player, score from game_info
      )
     ) p
group by player
order by sum(score) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT player, SUM(score)
FROM
(SELECT player_1 AS player, score
 FROM t
 UNION ALL
 SELECT player_2 as player, score
 FROM t) sub
GROUP BY player
```

You have to union the player 1 results with the player 2 results, so that you have one result with just player and score. Of course, the scores will be listed twice in this view, one for each player. In my query, the result is called sub. Based on sub, you can group by player and sum their scores.